# Dynamically assign variable names for vectors in R?

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I'm new to R and I am trying to create variables referencing vectors within a for loop, where the index of the loop will be appended to the variable name.  However, the following code below, where I'm trying to insert the new vectors into the appropriate place in the larger data frame, is not working and I've tried many variations of get(), as.vector(), eval() etc. in the data frame construction function.

I want num_incorrect.8 and num_incorrect.9 to be vectors with a value of 0 and then be inserted into mytable.

```
cols_to_update <- c(8,9)

for (i in cols_to_update)
{
#column name of insertion point
insertion_point <- paste("num_correct",".",i,sep="")
#create the num_incorrect col -- as a vector of 0s
assign(paste("num_incorrect",".",i,sep=""), c(0))

#index of insertion point
thespot <- which(names(mytable)==insertion_point)
#insert the num_incorrect vector and rebuild mytable 
mytable <- data.frame(mytable[1:thespot], as.vector(paste("num_incorrect",".",i,sep="")), mytable[(thespot+1):ncol(mytable)])
#update values
mytable[paste("num_incorrect",".",i,sep="")] <- mytable[paste("num_tries",".",i,sep="")] - mytable[paste("num_correct",".",i,sep="")] 
}
```

When I look at how the column insertion went, it looks like this:

```
 [626] "num_correct.8"                                         
 [627] "as.vector.paste..num_incorrect........i..sep........2"
...
 [734] "num_correct.9"                                         
 [735] "as.vector.paste..num_incorrect........i..sep........3"
```

Basically, it looks like it's taking my commands as literal text. The last line of code works as expected and creates new columns at the end of the data frame (since the line before it didn't insert the column into the proper place):

```
[1224] "num_incorrect.8"                                       
[1225] "num_incorrect.9"
```

I am kind of out of ideas, so if someone could please give me an explanation of what's wrong and why, and how to fix it, I would appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. Could you share a small reproducible example representing your `mytable` ?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in the second last lines of your code, excluding the comments where you are creating the vector and adding it to your data frame.

You just need to add the vector and update the name. You can remove the `assign` function as it's not creating a vector instead just assigning a value of `0` to the variable.

Instead of the second last line of your code put the code below and it should work.

```
#insert the vector at the desired location
mytable <- data.frame(mytable[1:thespot], newCol = vector(mode='numeric',length = nrow(mytable)), mytable[(thespot+1):ncol(mytable)])

#update the name of new location
names(mytable)[thespot + 1] = paste("num_incorrect",".",i,sep="")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; your suggestion worked.  However, if I want to do this instead:

assign(paste("accuracy",".",i,sep=""), vector(mode='numeric',length = nrow(mytable)))

How can I reference the vector and insert it using the data.frame() function as I was trying to do in my original question?  Or is it impossible to do it that way?